# How to get response value from NSObject class through AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I am following this tutorial to learn `AfNetworking` in `IOS` And I am using the following function to get the response from the server:

For example, I have one method which returns a value:

```
{
    __block id response = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:URLString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        response=responseObject;
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", response);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    NSLog(@" return Dic ==> %@",response);
    return response;
}
```

What I want is to write a function which will returns the response as a `NSDictionary` after getting response. I don't know the syntax.Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure... you probably don't need to declare the NSDictionary as a block object though:

```
{
    if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *response = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning the response outside of the success block will only contain the blank `NSDictionary` object you initialized. Your encapsulating method could have a block as a parameter to be executed when you receive the response.

```
-(void)makeServiceCallSuccess:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))success
           failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:URLString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        response = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        success(response);
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", response);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        failure(error);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Then you'll call the method like this:

```
[YourClass makeServiceCallSuccess:^(NSDictionary *response) {

    //Do stuff with 'response'

} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    //Do stuff with 'error'
}];
```